# I can't use fluent validation on all points

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-identity, fluentvalidation

I used the fluentvalidation library to create validations for my viewmodels. The validation messages I wrote are valid at some points, and at some points they are crushed under another message. I searched how to solve this but couldn't find a definitive solution.

ViewModel

```
   public class SignUpViewModel
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

    }
```

Validation

```
 public class SignUpVMValidator : AbstractValidator<SignUpViewModel>
    {
        public SignUpVMValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.UserName)
                .NotNull().WithMessage("Kullanıcı Adı Boş Bırakılamaz")
                .MinimumLength(6).WithMessage("Kullanıcı Adı Minimum 6 Karakterden Oluşmalıdır")
                .MaximumLength(20).WithMessage("Kullanıcı Adı Maksimum 20 Karakterden Oluşmalıdır");

            RuleFor(x => x.Password)
                .MinimumLength(6).WithMessage("Şifre Minimum 6 Karakterden Oluşmalıdır")
                .MaximumLength(20).WithMessage("Şifre Maksimum 20 Karakterden Oluşmalıdır")
                .NotNull().WithMessage("Şifre Boş Bırakılamaz").NotEmpty().WithMessage("Şifre Boş Bırakılamaz");

            RuleFor(x => x.Email)
                .NotNull().WithMessage("Email Boş Bırakılamaz")
                .EmailAddress();
        }
    }
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(SignUpViewModel signUpViewModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            AppUser user = signUpViewModel.Adapt<AppUser>();
            IdentityResult result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, signUpViewModel.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
             await   userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user,"User");
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
            }
            else
            {
                AddModelError(result);
            }
        }
        return View(signUpViewModel);
    }
```

Razor

```
<form asp-action="Index" method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="mb-3">
         <label class="form-label" asp-for="UserName">Kullanıcı Adı</label>
                <input asp-for="UserName" type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Kullanıcı Adı">
          <span asp-validation-for="UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
          <label class="form-label" asp-for="Email">Mail Adresi</label>
              <input asp-for="Email" type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Mail Adresi">
          <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
        
    <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label" asp-for="Password">Şifre</label>
                 <input asp-for="Password" type="password" class="form-control" id="userpassword" placeholder="Şifrenizi Oluşturun">
            <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
            
    <div class="mt-3 text-end">
        <button class="btn btn-primary w-sm waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">Kayıt Ol</button>
    </div>
        
      <div class="mt-4 text-center">
            <p class="text-muted mb-0">Zaten Bir Hesabınız Var Mı ? <a href="Login" class="fw-medium text-primary">Giriş Sayfası</a></p>
       </div>
    </form>
```

I triggered the form without typing anything in the first photo and the default Annotions returned in English

[image: Validation is Not Working]

In the second photo, I got a response as I set it.
What I want is to be able to adjust the Annotations in the first photo as I want. I did this by trying the `NotNull()` and `NotEmpty()` methods in turn, but without success.

[image: Validation is Working]

> If I make the properties nullable, this problem disappears, I can understand why, but what I'm wondering is how can I override the system's automatic message without making it nullable?

Comment: do you need error messages in English ?

Comment: No, I need messages of my own choosing not system message.

Comment: `AddModelError(result);` is never called if ModelState is not valid.

Comment: It works, the check there is not model check, it's identity check.                                     `  public void AddModelError(IdentityResult result)
        {
            foreach (var item in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", item.Description);
            }
        }`  Its Custom Method.

Comment: Validations are working, I don't have a problem with it, the only problem is that the messages are displayed to the user, except for the message I sent, in the blank controls. I can't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

> What I want is to be able to adjust the Annotations in the first photo
> as I want. I did this by trying the NotNull() and NotEmpty() methods
> in turn, but without success.

This is a compatibility issue when using Asp.net Core build-in Validation and the FluentValidation.

After FluentValidation is executed, any other validator providers will also have a chance to execute. This means you can mix FluentValidation auto-validation with DataAnnotations attributes (or any other ASP.NET ModelValidatorProvider implementation).

And if we disable the Asp.net core DataAnnotations Validation (refer to this article:[Compatibility with ASP.NET's built-in Validation](https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation.AspNetCore#compatibility-with-aspnets-built-in-validation)), it will still meet your issue, because of the client-side validation.

So, as a workaround, I suggest you can mix FluentValidation auto-validation with DataAnnotations attributes, and set required error message twice, like this:

The DataAnnotations validation:

```
public class SignUpViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Kullanıcı Adı Boş Bırakılamaz")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email Boş Bırakılamaz")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Şifre Boş Bırakılamaz")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

}
```

The FluentValidation:

```
public class SignUpVMValidator : AbstractValidator<SignUpViewModel>
{
    public SignUpVMValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.UserName)
            .NotNull().WithMessage("Kullanıcı Adı Boş Bırakılamaz")
            .MinimumLength(6).WithMessage("Kullanıcı Adı Minimum 6 Karakterden Oluşmalıdır")
            .MaximumLength(20).WithMessage("Kullanıcı Adı Maksimum 20 Karakterden Oluşmalıdır");

        RuleFor(x => x.Password)
            .MinimumLength(6).WithMessage("Şifre Minimum 6 Karakterden Oluşmalıdır")
            .MaximumLength(20).WithMessage("Şifre Maksimum 20 Karakterden Oluşmalıdır")
            .NotNull().WithMessage("Şifre Boş Bırakılamaz").NotEmpty().WithMessage("Şifre Boş Bırakılamaz");

        RuleFor(x => x.Email)
            .NotNull().WithMessage("Email Boş Bırakılamaz")
            .EmailAddress();
    }
}
```

Finally, since this issue relates the FluentValudation, you can also submit a feedback to them, might be they will provide a build-in method to solve this issue.

Comment: Yes, I don't have a problem if I do as you did, but I don't want to define DataAnnotations on my models. This creates a situation against SOLID principles. A code where I can turn off other validations directly would be more useful for me.